# ObjectLinkProvider failed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, project-server

I have many problems in deploying a sharepoint solution from sharepoint 2010 to sharepoint 2013 , but i got error ObjectLinkProvider failed

so far i can't a solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand your question well, but I will tell you what I know about `ObjectLinkProvider`

The `ObjectLinkProvider` includes methods for managing web object links in Project Server and links to external objects such as list items in SharePoint sites.

The `ObjectLinkProvider` service is **deprecated** in Project Server 2013 and is not usable with Project Online. see the Deprecated features section in [What's new and what's out for developers in Project 2013.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee767690.aspx)

**Microsoft** recommends that you use the `RelatedItemManager` class in the SharePoint CSOM to create OLP-type apps for both on-premises installations of Project Server 2013 and for Project Online.

**Note:** The Microsoft.SharePoint namespace does not include a RelatedItemManager class.

For more details check [ObjectLinkProvider class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvcobjectlinkprovider.objectlinkprovider_di_pj14mref.aspx)